# HIde Rss Feed Category name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed, rss2

Im using wordpress 3.6, and /feed to get rss field,

I dont want to show category name in rss feed like,

```
<category>
    <![CDATA[ News ]]>
</category>
<category>
    <![CDATA[ A ]]>
</category>
<category>
    <![CDATA[ B ]]>
</category>
<category>
    <![CDATA[ C ]]>
</category>
```

In my above example "News"- is the category title and "A","B" and "C" - is tags related to this post.

And here I dont want to exclude "News" category in my rss feed but I want to show only "A", "B" and "C" as category's.

Basically I want to "hide the first category called News in my feed code".

Can anyone please help me to fix this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your expected out ? `XML` or just A . B . C ?

Comment: xml only.. I need exact rss2 format. Just want to hide the category name and only want to show tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do little deep customize,

the solution is,

You want to customize the_category_rss('rss2') function output in feed-rss2.php.

Comment: Ya thank you so much, I have modified the_category_rss() function in feed.php,
I just commented out the following lines,
if ( !empty($categories) ) foreach ( (array) $categories as $category ) {
  $cat_names[] = sanitize_term_field('name', $category->name, $category->term_id, 'category', $filter);
 }
and now it's working fine.